# Оптимизация Layout под все разрешения смартфонов и планшетов

Tags: java, android-layout

Необходимо оптимизировать *Layout* под все разрешения аппаратов.

Пробовал делать через `normal,large,xlarge`. Так на *Nexus 6* смотрится замечательно, а на *Nexus 5, 4* и более бюджетных смартфонах смотрится плохо, с огромными отступами и прочим.

Узнал что есть более новый способ:

```
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw360dp
layout-sw384dp
layout-sw400dp
layout-sw480dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw768dp
layout-sw800dp
```

И даже тут получилось не все гладко. В *Android Studio* *nexus 5* присвоил себе папку с `360dp`, а *nexus 4* взял `384dp`. Как так?

У *5 нексуса* больше точек на дюйм, чем у *4*, или это баг студии?

Далее начал тестировать на эмуляторах, и *Asus nexus 7* вообще использовал папку `400dp`.

Возникает вопрос: возможно ли более точно подогнать *Layout-ы* под устройства (кроме гугловских)?

Кстати, *dpi* брал с [этого ресурса](http://random1911.net/that_a_web_designer_should_know_about_mobile_devices).
Там пишут *dpi* по вертикали. Может быть, кто-нибудь знает другие сайты, где есть больше *dpi* по вертикали?

Comment: http://www.google.com/design/tool/devices/

Comment: Какие конкретно у вас проблемы компоновки? Вы используете абсолютные значения, вместо относительных?

Comment: Проблемы устранил, да я использую абсолютные значения, спасибо за сайт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная статья по этому вопросу - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Также помогает неплохой сайт с описание девайсов - http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php

Да, у 5 нексуса больше точек на дюйм чем у 4, а у 6 еще больше.

Обычно на практике удобно создать один лаяут, а все отступы и прочее выносить в dimens, которые уже раскидывать по нужным размерам.

Кроме того выровнять элементы весами, разнообразным иконкам задавать размеры - wrap_content по ширине и высоте.