# Какие лучше использовать папки для ресурсов в Android?

Tags: android

Создаю приложение, ещё не решил, буду ли поддерживать планшеты, или нет.

Будет ли достаточно использовать папки:

```
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```

для изображений (и аналогичные `values` для размеров), чтобы контролировать отображение на различных экранах *Android*-устройств? И какие разрешения макетов Photoshop нужны для разработки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно, даже многова-то, я б оставил только xxhdpi - для остальных картинки будут скалиться в минус интерполяцией и получится норм, но кроме иконки.
Макет я б тоже выбрал один - 2560×1440 - QHD (Включая статус бар и навигейшн бар). Ну если сильно хочется то можно еще отдельно для 1280x720 и 1920x1080.

См. http://www.google.com/design/tool/devices/

А также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435686/176928

**UPD.** Также следует учитывать что `xxhdpi` появилось с 16 апи, а `xxxhdpi`  с 18, но тем не менее картинки будут отображаться и на меньших API - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29577760/1159507

Общая политика андроид по этому поводу - предоставлять картинки в дополнительных разрешениях необходимо, только если вы не удовлетворены качеством, того как андроид скалит их. Типичный пример это логотип с отрисованными вручную буквами - на них часто бывают заметны небольшие искажения.

Кроме всего прочего это уменьшает размер APK и упрощает разработку.

По поводу того что это снижает нагрузку на телефон - никогда об этом не слышал, но учитывая что в оффициальной документации рекомендуется предоставлять возможности системе самой скалить изображения (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), думаю нагрузкой на телефон можно пренебречь.

**UPD2.** Вот статья от **Dianne Hackborn** (Software engineer on the Android platform) на эту тему: https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8

> "You don't need to supply bitmaps for every possible density, Android
>   will scale your bitmaps (typically when they are loaded) to match the
>   current density."

Comment: спасибо за совет! но разве, не желательно ли хранить изображения под все разрешения? где то читал, меньше нагрузка на телефон будет.

Comment: @iamtihonov обновил ответ

Comment: @iamtihonov Все написано верно, за исключением того, что бюджетным устройствам небольшой диагонали (mdpi - hdpi), с малым размером оперативной памяти и слабым процессором будет все же довольно тяжко обрабатывать большие картинки (по "весу" либо разрешению), поэтому каталог `drawable-hdpi/` с оптимизированными изображениями я бы для таких все же сделал

Comment: @ander Хорошо все написано, только как понимать: "если сильно хочется то можно еще отдельно для 1280x720 и 1920x1080"? Если их добавлять, то только с определенным смыслом. Для 1920x1080 я предполагаю для лучшего качества изображений, а зачем тогда для 1280x720? Смысл вижу, как вы написали, когда качество не удовлетворяет, после сжатия или растягивания определенных изображений.

Comment: @iamtihonov Да, добавлять их нужно если не удовлетворяет качество но по другим параметрам: типичный телефон с 2560×1440 - это 6'' дюймовый типа Nexus 6, а с 1280x720 - 4.7'' типа Nexus 4. Соль в том что у Nexus 6 экран физически больше и на нем больше влазит. Например если у Nexus 4 в типичном списке помещается 2-3 елемента, то у Nexus 6 влазит 4 елемента. Поэтому иногда делают отдельный дизайн с измененной компоновкой и пропорциями элементов.